# How can I list all numbers relatively prime to X? (but less than X)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Given a number X how can I find all (or most) numbers that are relatively prime to and less than X?

Ideally I'd like this function to tell me the largest relative primes first.

Comment: "Ideally I'd like this function to tell me the largest primes first." Note that just because $a$ is relatively prime to $b$, does not mean $a$ is prime. e.g. $4$ and $9$

Comment: Check this out : http://www.math-magic.com/misc/rel_prime.htm. The problem boils down to find prime factorization of the number.

Comment: @Gaurav that link is now a 404 can you please relink?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the number (as you mention in a comment) is about $2^{1024},$ then the task is hopeless. At least 8.4% of the numbers below $X$ are coprime to it (for $X$ of this size), so there are well over $10^{300}$ numbers coprime to and smaller than $X$.

If every atom in the universe was a 1 THz computer that had been operating since the beginning of the universe, you'd only have time to find the first $10^{109}$ numbers. You would be further from your goal than a single electron would be from the universe.

Comment: Yes, my unstated goal was to understand the magnitude and difficulty of the task... so that by understanding this concept, I understand why RSA is considered strong for cryptography.

Comment: @makerofthings7: I guessed that might be your goal, so I slanted the answer toward that purpose. Glad to see it helped!

Comment: +1 for an answer that just makes me feel despair in general

Comment: I'd like to go before the beginning of your "universe" and start the computation there - that would give you ample  time to talk  of  all  the  nonsense that you  are talking here

Comment: @gpasch Hmm, what's that?

Comment: @Charles, it's rude to delete your question without engaging with the comment I left there.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, didn’t mean to be rude, just thought deletion wasn’t the right thing for wrongheaded and somewhat duplicative questions.

Answer (score 5):

Dirichlet came up with a (non-trivial) proof that every arithmetic progression $ax+b$ for GCD$(a,b)=1$ contains an infinite number of primes.

This means that there is no largest number $k$ such that GCD$(k,X)=1$.  Instead, we usually consider all the positive numbers relatively prime to $X$ which are less than $X$.  The count of such numbers is given by [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

Assuming that you wish to find such numbers $k\lt X$, note that the largest of these is always $k=X-1$ and do a GCD test on each successively smaller number.

There aren't very many short-cuts to this process, however, it is possible to reduce the number space you are considering by going through the primes in succession and finding those which divide $X$ (i.e., factoring $X$ in the process) and then automatically discarding such numbers from your GCD test.  In fact, once you have determined any particular GCD$(k,X)\gt 1$, you can use that factor to eliminate all numbers $k$ which have it.

Note that GCD$(k,X)=$GCD$(X-k,X)$ so that you need only consider the first (or last) half of the number space in order to capture all the numbers relatively prime to $X$.  Note further that all factors $d$ of $X$ which are useful in determining relative primality are $d\le \sqrt X$.

Comment: Yes, given the result of Euler's totient function, I'd like to find all numbers it is counting.  Outside of a GCD test on each number (and getting a pass or fail) I'm hoping for a shortcut to reduce the quantity of numbers I need to test.

Comment: Two things you can do are to factor $X$ (if you have time) or consider each number $k$ in succession until GCD$(k,X)=d\gt 1$.  Then skip all numbers having factor $d$.  Add any additional $d_i$ to a list of "factors of numbers to be skipped" and you probably have the best possible chance of finding all the relatively prime ones.

Answer (score 3):

1. Start with the ordered set $(1,2,3,\ldots, X-1)$
2. Ignore $1$ and leave it in the set: $1$ and $X-1$ are co-prime to $X$.
3. Take the next element $n$ remaining in the set (initially $2$).  If $n^2 \gt X$ then move to step 5; otherwise if $n$ divides $X$ then remove $n$ and all multiples of $n$ and $\frac{X}{n}$ and all multiples of $\frac{X}{n}$ from the set; if $n$ has not already been removed and  $n$ does not divide $X$ then that tells you that $n$ and $X-n$ are coprime to $X$.
4. Repeat step 3.
5. The remaining ordered set is your solution.

You might be able to speed this sieve up slightly by restricting checking the division to prime numbers, but the time saved could be less than the time taken to program it.

Comment: If you wish to apply this to a number whose decimal representation is over a million digits long, it might be worth to bother with optimization. :-)

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: I somehow doubt anybody wants to know **all** the numbers coprime to such a large number: they would face a significant storage problem. But a minor adaptation to my algorithm of limiting the size of the ordered set would tell them the largest coprimes reasonably quickly.

Comment: I am not storing them, but reprocessing the numbers for RSA purposes, and yes the value is 2^1024 (large).

Comment: What about a computer-based number theory course with a jerk for a professor? :-)

Comment: @makerofthings7: If the number you are interested in is $2^{1024}$ then it's much much easier. You just take all the odd numbers below it.